# Store Lightning Dashboard as PNG in Files

Tags: api, dashboard, contentversion, contentdocument, reports-api

The use case here is that I need to fetch the image/png of Lightning Dashboard and store it in Files via Apex

So first, I try to do a callout to Dashboards REST API -

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

req.setEndpoint('https://BASE-URL/analytics/download/lightning-dashboard/01ZXXXXXXXXXXXX.png');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+Userinfo.getSessionId());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
req.setMethod('GET');

HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

if(res.getStatusCode() == 302){
    req.setEndpoint(res.getHeader('Location'));
    res = new Http().send(req);
    system.debug('response-->' + res.getbody());
}
```

Then, once I get the results, I try to store it in Files using by creating a new ContentVersion record -

```
ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
cv.ContentLocation = 'S';
cv.VersionData = res.getBodyAsBlob();
cv.Title = 'Sample File';
cv.PathOnClient = 'test.png';

insert cv;
```

However when I download the png file and view the file, it looks like the file didn't generate properly -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of the API, called out in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_download_reference_download.htm):

> Downloads are requested by entering the URI in a browser address bar.
>
> Use of this API from Apex isn’t supported.